# Angular 8 - Hide mat menu button if there are no items

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an `*ngFor` in which I am setting the values of `mat-menu-item` values in order to populate a `mat-menu`.

The values are set dynamically with the use of a filter.

The problem is that sometimes the the custom filter pipe doesn't return results and the `mat-menu` remains empty.

```
...

<button mat-icon-button
    matTooltip="Select alternative style"
    [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
    <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
    <div *ngFor="let style of styles | filterPipe: filteredLayers[i].name">
         <button  mat-menu-item>
             <span> {{ style.name }} </span>
         </button>
    </div>
</mat-menu>

...
```

The `filterPipe` is like this

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'filterPipe'
})
export class FilterStylePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(styles: any[], layer: string): any {
    const result = styles.filter(elem => elem.name.startsWith(layer.substring(0, 3)));
    if(result.length!==0) {
      return result;
    }
  }
}
```

How can i dynamically not show (or not create) the`mat-icon-button` or the `mat-menu`?
Or even disabling it?

### ADDENDUM

One possible solution is this to implement a function (`menuIsNotEmpty(i)`) that returns a boolean

```
...

<button mat-icon-button *ngIf="menuIsNotEmpty(i)"
    matTooltip="Select alternative style"
    [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
    <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
</button>

...
```

Whereas

```
  menuIsNotEmpty(index) {
    const result = this.styles.filter(elem => elem.name.startsWith(this.filteredLayers[index].name.substring(0, 3)));
    if(result.length!==0) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

It is working but it has redundant code and the filtering is done twice to the array. I dont think that is the optimal way to do it. I m still looking on how to do it dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(styles | filterPipe: filteredLayers[i].name).length > 0">    
    <button mat-icon-button
        matTooltip="Select alternative style"
        [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
        <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
        <div *ngFor="let style of styles | filterPipe: filteredLayers[i].name">
             <button  mat-menu-item>
                 <span> {{ style.name }} </span>
             </button>
        </div>
    </mat-menu>
</ng-container>
```

Please double check this expression `(styles | filterPipe: filteredLayers[i].name).length > 0` for null reference exception as well.

Comment: ok that worked and its a bit more dynamic. Less code on the component too.

Answer (score 2):

I'll add new variable to .ts file like this

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'filterPipe'
})
export class FilterStylePipe implements PipeTransform {
  myResult:any;

  transform(styles: any[], layer: string): any {
    const result = styles.filter(elem => elem.name.startsWith(layer.substring(0, 3)));
    if(result.length!==0) {
      this.myResult = result;
    }
  }
}
```

And in the template I'll use `*ngIf`

```
...

<button *ngIf="myResult" mat-icon-button
    matTooltip="Select alternative style"
    [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
    <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
</button>
<mat-menu *ngIf="myResult" #menu="matMenu">
    <div *ngFor="let style of styles | filterPipe: filteredLayers[i].name">
         <button  mat-menu-item>
             <span> {{ style.name }} </span>
         </button>
    </div>
</mat-menu>

...
```

I hope that will help!

Comment: the custom filter is not in the component file. It is another class. I dont think the variable will be visible

Comment: Understand, I'll look for other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The `FilterStylePipe` does not return anything when there are no matching items. It should return an empty array.

```
 @Pipe({
      name: 'filterPipe'
    })
    export class FilterStylePipe implements PipeTransform {
      transform(styles: any[], layer: string): any {
        const result = styles.filter(elem => elem.name.startsWith(layer.substring(0, 3)));
         return result;
      }
    }
```